# How to make WebStorm IDE to correctly recognise file type?

Tags: webstorm

## The Background

1. (Within JetsBrains / WebStorm IDE) Initially I created a file called `HelloWorldContainer` - accidentally left out the `.js` extension (I meant to create `HelloWorldContainer.js`).
2. WebStorm asks what file type I would like that file to be (e.g. JavaScript? Text File? HTML? etc.). I accidentally hit the enter key - and WebStorm has treated it as a text file.
3. Realising my mistake, I renamed the file to `HelloWorldContainer.js` (adding that `.js` to the end`). Hoping this will change the file type back to a JavaScript file.

## The Problem

For some reason, WebStorm is still "seeing" `HelloWorldContainer.js` as a text file??? (snapshot below). This is a problem as now my JavaScript Live Templates no longer load for this file.

Snapshot 1: showing `HelloWorld.js` as a JavaScript file, whilst `HelloWorldContainer.js` showing as a text file (huh?).

[image]

Snapshot 2: for `HelloWorld.js`, WebStorm knows it is a JavaScript file - Live Templates successfully loaded as a result. (Cmd + J)

[image]

Snapshot 3: for `HelloWorldContainer.js`, WebStorm (for some reason) fail to recognise it as a JavaScript file - the JavaScript Live Templates fail to load as a result. (Cmd + J)

[image]

How to I make WebStorm recognise `HelloWorldContainer.js` as a JavaScript file again?

Note: I've tried...

- delete the `HelloWorldContainer.js` and recreate it again, WebStorm is still seeing it as a text file.
- rename `HelloWorldContainer.js` to `HelloWorldContainer2.js` - WebStorm now sees it as a JavaScript file. But if I rename it back to original name, WebStorm sees it as a text file again. (I really want to call my file `HelloWorldContainer.js`! :-)

## The Solution

Just tried out the solution provided below (by @LazyOne)- works like a charm! Some snapshots for note keeping...

Snapshot 4: remove the offending pattern.

[image]

Snapshot 5: WebStorm now sees the file as a JavaScript again!

[image]

Comment: I'd say this is something you should Jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Webstorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Locate `Text` entry in top list
3. Remove offending pattern from bottom list -- most likely will be `HelloWorldContainer.js` or very similar
4. Hit `OK` and wait till project will be re-indexed.

Comment: Works like a charm - added snapshots in the original question for documentation. Thank you!!!